# Livewire: concealing sensitive data

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a full page component, with automatically bound properties from the route:

```php
    class ReviewFormComponent extends Component {
    
        public User $user;
        public Booking $booking;
    
        //...
    }
```

What I don’t want is to expose primary key fields and any other sensitive information. I read in docs “Public props are visible to the front end, you SHOULD NOT store sensitive data in them.”

Does that include properties of Eloquent models? Does the V2 'rules=[]' help here?

Other than specifying fields as ‘hidden’ in the model, do I have another option here?

TIA

Comment: Change the access modifier to private, like private User $user; then define another public variable to store only the non-sensitive data by assigning the data using the mount method from the private to the public variable.

Comment: @AliAli are you sure that is that necessary? I have tried to access the properties from the browser with the Livewire js class and I can't seem to access them that way.